# How to add text under Font Awesome icons of handheld footer bar of Storefront?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am configuring Storefront theme. The handheld footer bar of Storefront shows links on mobile devices. However, now, it just shows Font Awesome icons (not include text). How to include text under Font Awesome icons in this case?

I have tried to edit some codes, but the search bar appeared as an error in handheld footer bar of storefront.

Php codes added to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar_links', 'jk_add_home_link' );
function jk_add_home_link( $links ) {
$new_links = array(
    'home' => array(
        'priority' => 10,
        'callback' => 'jk_home_link',
    ),
);

$links = array_merge( $new_links, $links );

return $links;
}

function jk_home_link() {
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Home' ) . '</a>';
}
```

CSS:

```
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li.home > a:before {
content: "\f015";
}
```

The text “Home” will not be displayed if I use above codes. How to display it under the Font Awesome icon?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but the text is hidden by this property decleration:

```
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li > a {
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

play around with the indent to position it. Not tried.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same question answered by myself on https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511882/11225860, coping it from there.

The text is hidden due to "text-indent: -9999px;" so you can change it as follows.

Here I am additionally added "line-height:" to arrange position of the text.

```
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li > a {
  text-indent: 0px;
  line-height: 95px;
 }
```

If you need to adjust position of the icons, you can add following css and make changes on the value.

```
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li>a::before {
  line-height: 2;
}
```