# Display text as well as icon in Woocommerce handheld menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is [great documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customize-the-links-in-the-handheld-footer-bar/) on how to change or remove the handheld menu links in WooCommerce available. However, I have noticed that many mobile designs (mweb and apps) are trending towards showing text as well as icons for handheld menus. I want to display the text for the link UNDERNEATH the icon, as well as the icon itself.

It looks like WooCommerce has intentionally hidden the text for the handheld link using CSS:

```
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li>a {
  height: 4.235801032em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 999;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
}
```

My suspicion is that I should just change the `text-indent` and the text will show back up. For example, in the instructions provided by WooCommerce to add a new home link to the handheld menu, my thought was that changing `text-indent` in the CSS would allow me to display both the icon and 'Home'.

```
function jk_home_link() {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Home' ) . '</a>';
}
```

But, I can't quite figure out how to "undo" the text-indent so that the text for the link shows as well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The text is hidden due to "text-indent: -9999px;" so you can change it as follows.

Here I am additionally added "line-height:" to arrange position of the text.

```
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li > a {
  text-indent: 0px;
  line-height: 95px;
 }
```

If you need to adjust position of the icons, you can add following css and make changes on the value.

```
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li>a::before {
  line-height: 2;
}
```